# SFMC Filter Activity - Date + -

Tags: marketing-cloud, filters, sqlserver

When creating a filter in the Marketing Cloud, say when filtering a Data Extension, you can base any of the statements in the filter off of a date field. The question I have relates to when using the month as a parameter of the date statement.

Example: I want to run an email on the first of every month for people who made a purchase last month.

If I were to do: "OrderDate *is* **before** **today** AND OrderDate *is* **Greater than Today - 1 Month**,

Would it simply apply 30 days as a month or would it apply any logic based on the current date? For example, if it was June 1st, would it only go back as far as May 2nd, or would it know that May had 31 days so it needs to go back 31 days? Or does it pick up that its June so it only goes back 30 days? Or just by default 30 days?

I'm just looking for consistent behaviour that I can leave in an automation, so any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used it earlier and it calculates itself based on the days in the month. So, it does not default to 30 days and adjusts based on the days in the month (I believe it handles leap year as well). You can run a quick test to verify it before you automate it.

Unfortunately, this is not very well documented in SFMC guides.

Comment: Excellent to hear, thank you very much for the insight!